# Why do I have to PUT new documents to a nested URI, if mapping types have been removed?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm on Elasticsearch 7.14.0 where [mapping types have been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).

If I run the following:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/products/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name": "Toast"
}
'
```

I get

```
{
  "error" : "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/products/1?pretty] and method [PUT], allowed: [POST]",
  "status" : 405
}
```

It seems that elastic wants me `PUT` it in an `/index/type/` URI:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/pop/products/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name": "Toast"
}
'
{
  "_index" : "pop",
  "_type" : "products",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

I am wondering why I must have a nested URI [indicating a type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_indexing_employee_documents.html), if mapping types have been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `_doc` to your put request call as shown below

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/products/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name": "Toast"
}
'
```

As mentioned in [elasticsearch official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#:%7E:text=In%207.0%2C%20_doc%20represents%20the,not%20be%20removed%20in%208.0.) after mapping types were removed in 7.x, you need to add , `_doc` (which does not represent a document type rather it represents the endpoint name) for the document index, get, and delete APIs

Comment: Amazing, thank you @ESCoder. I have asked a follow on question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972048/how-do-i-create-a-default-mapping-for-a-field-on-my-documents-that-will-not-be).