# How do I create a default mapping for a field on my documents, that will not be made redundant in the next major version of Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm on Elasticsearch 7.14.0 where [mapping types have been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).

Following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970220/why-do-i-have-to-put-new-documents-to-a-nested-uri-if-mapping-types-have-been-r) I have learned that the generic URI to `PUT` documents is `/[index]/_doc/[id]`.

I want to create a default mapping for my documents on the `name` field:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/products?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "name":{
            "analyzer":"edge_ngram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer":"standard",
            "type":"text"
         }
      }
   },
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "edge_ngram":{
               "type":"edge_ngram",
               "min_gram":"2",
               "max_gram":"25",
               "token_chars":[
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "edge_ngram_analyzer":{
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "edge_ngram"
               ],
               "tokenizer":"standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

However creating a new document doesn't apply the analyzer:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/products/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name": "Toast"
}
'

curl -X GET "localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty"
{
  "took" : 1026,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Toast"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried creating the mapping under the `_doc` type, but am getting the following error:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/products?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "mappings":{
       "_doc":{
          "properties":{
             "name":{
                "analyzer":"edge_ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer":"standard",
                "type":"text"
             }
          }
       }
    },
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "edge_ngram":{
               "type":"edge_ngram",
               "min_gram":"2",
               "max_gram":"25",
               "token_chars":[
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "edge_ngram_analyzer":{
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "edge_ngram"
               ],
               "tokenizer":"standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

However, [I've read that](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types):

> **Elasticsearch 8.x:** Specifying types in requests is no longer supported. The include_type_name parameter is removed.

How do I create a default mapping for a field on my documents, that will not be made redundant in the next major version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: can you please add your search query as well ?

Comment: @ESCoder my search query is in the middle code block, `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty"`

Comment: what is your search query body ? You have only shared the search query API and the search result

Comment: Nothing strange in what you shared, search query return doc origine value, but can filter by a query in ngram because of the analyser

Comment: @ESCoder Oh sorry I misunderstood. I am performing the empty search, so am not including a body. I think I am missing something because I thought the result would return with the analysed fields, to confirm that it had been correctly analysed. However it seems the correct way to test that the field is being analysed is to perform a search query only that analyser could return, i.e. `{ "name": "To" }`? I will test this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was due to a misunderstanding on my part (new to ES). I thought the returned result from a search would include the underlying analysis of any fields. When I perform a partially matching search, the document is correctly returned, so the above mapping works as intended:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "To"
        }
    }
}
'
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.41501677,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.41501677,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Toast"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```